npm error "unable to get local issuer certificate" while trying to install Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x64.4.0.6280
When I try to install Azure Function Core Tools, I am getting the below error. I checked through my browser the link where GET request is failing and I was able to download the zip package, so I think no proxy issue in this case.
npm error path C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node lib/install.js
npm error attempting to GET "https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/4.0.6280/Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x64.4.0.6280.zip"
npm error Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

After npm install fails, I installed Azure Function Core Tools manually in Windows by the SI file, however when I tried to run my project, I get the below error.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\A\Source\Repos\nodeV4Prog\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}



npm error "unable to get local issuer certificate" while trying to install Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x64.4.0.6280

To resolve this error, you can resolve the issue by setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 locally.
Note: This will disable the SSL/TLS certificate verification and allow the installation to proceed, not recommended for production environments.
If the system is under a secure connection of any organization, set the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable to the custom CA certificate, check the solution provided by @Jordan*.
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<path_to_certificate.cer>  

Uninstall nodejs and npm and re-install again.
Add the pathC:\Users\uname\AppData\Roaming\npm under Environment Variables=>User variables=>Path:

Install the Azure functions core tools using the command:
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true --force

This installs the Functions core tools successfully:
C:\Users\uname>npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
npm warn deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)

changed 35 packages in 1m

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details


Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\A\Source\Repos\nodeV4Prog\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js' at Module._resolveFilename


Remove node_modules before running the project.
Run npm install to install all the dependencies.

Run the function using command func start:
C:\Users\uname\node>func start

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce69XXXfc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-09-19T07:08:30.802Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        httpTrigger: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-09-19T07:08:33.386Z] Executing 'Functions.httpTrigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5383083e-b9e5-4525XXXdabb5a)
[2024-09-19T07:08:33.480Z] Http function processed request for url "http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger"
[2024-09-19T07:08:33.566Z] Executed 'Functions.httpTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=5383083e-b9e5XXX6e7dabb5a, Duration=208ms)

